# Basil Plant leaves discoloration

Tags: basil, discoloration

[image]What is the discoloration on my basil leaves? the bottom leaves of the plants also have it and are yellow. Am i doing something wrong ?[image]

Comment: This basil is in a pot?  Could you please tell us about how and how often you water it, and what sort of sunlight it gets?

Comment: How long have you had this plant?

Comment: I have grown it from a seed back in july it’s gone through 3 transplants. It’s been in this very large planter pot in the 2nd week of October. I typically water it every 2-3 days. The pot is on a bench under a tree only gets sunlight a few hours a day.

Comment: Spider mites? Spray with soapy water. Basil is a sun plant, not a shade plant. More sun. I would not transplant an annual 3 times a season. Does not need such a large pot.

Comment: Are new leaves growing? Are they fine(deep green and not curled)? Is the weather especially cold last month where You are? Large pot + cold weather + clay-rich soil could make watering every 3 days too much for the transportation-shocked roots.